# Getting Unicode character in knitr R-figure snippet

Tags: r, unicode, character-encoding, plot, knitr

Currently I am making my figs using "unprincipled" (opportunistic) way to get Unicode characters right. For example:

```
<<ClassFig>>=
pdf('figs/figA.pdf', h=6, w=6, encoding='CP1250')
plot(x, y, xlab='rečenica')
dev.off()
@
```

Now, I wonder how would I specify snippet (or global settings, as with opts_chunk$set()) properly to see Uncode characters that I need. For example:

```
<<ParadigmFig, fig.height=7, fig.width=15, out.width='1\\textwidth'>>=
plot(x, y, xlab='rečenica')
@
```

Currently, if I use the second, proper variant, I am getting dots instead of spec. character.

Answer (score 2):

Try generating this figure with `cairo_pdf()`.

```
cairo_pdf('test.pdf', family="Helvetica")
plot(1:10, (1:10)^2, xlab=enc2utf8("ąśćźół"))
dev.off()
```

It may be important to change the font `family` to one of which *knows* about *regional* characters (I'm using Polish letters above). For OS X, [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_OS_X) may give you a hint on font family selection.

Now let's set up `knitr` to use these settings. Create an uncached code chunk at the beginning of the document with calls to:

```
library("knitr")
library("tikzDevice")
opts_chunk$set(
   dev='cairo_pdf',
   dev.args=list(family='DejaVu Sans')
   #out.width='5in', 
   #fig.width=5,
   #fig.height=5/sqrt(2),
   #fig.path='figures-knitr/',
   #fig.align='center',
)
```

(I've commented out the options which are meaningless here, but which you may also be interested in some day). You may find more details on chunk options [here](http://yihui.name/knitr/options).

Here is an exemplary `.Rnw` file that (at least on my Linux) produces correct results:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1,plmath]{polski}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\begin{document}

<<cache=FALSE,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE>>=
options(Encoding="UTF-8")
library("knitr")
library("tikzDevice")
opts_chunk$set(
   dev='cairo_pdf',
   dev.args=list(family='Helvetica')
   #out.width='5in', 
   #fig.width=5,
   #fig.height=5/sqrt(2),
   #fig.path='figures-knitr/',
   #fig.align='center',
)
@

<<>>=
plot(1:10, (1:10)^2, xlab="ąśćźół")
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion, but without any success. I am using Mac OSX. Maybe that causes all problems?

Comment: Maybe you should choose a different font family? Pick anything from the [font list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_OS_X) and let me know if it helped (e.g. `Arial`, `Times`, or `Times New Roman`).

Comment: I tried so many things:
- your variant works in R, but not in Rnw/knitR (and I followed your advice exactly!);
- I also tried simply pdf('tmp.pdf', h=5, w=5, encoding='CP1250') and in Rnw with dev='pdf', dev.args=list(encoding='CP1250'), again, it worked in R but nor in Rnw/knitR
I am lost! The only way I am getting spec. character is to use:
<<something, eval=FALSE>>=
and to run that piece directly in R.

This is so annoying... :-(

Comment: I tried different font families as you suggested, but, again and again, no luck... Depending of what I use two outcomes appear: (a) dots if I do not use enc2utf8() or "<c4><8c><c4><86>" if I use enc2utf8(). So, it is good for loosing mind... :-(

Comment: I wonder why you are forcing Windows-1250 (CP1250) encoding. AFAIK, R on OS X always uses UTF-8 as native encoding. Also try calling `options(encoding="UTF-8")` from the above chunk of code. Don't give up, we'll solve it together, even if it'll take some time. I also had similar problems with knitr. What is the result of `Sys.getlocale()` when you call it from a knitr document?

Comment: Also, try to compile the .Rnw file with RStudio (CTRL+SHIFT+I).